# Initial conditions for shm

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

This is the part of the question from the book that I am studying,

"A mass of $0.75\:\mathrm{kg}$ is attached to one end of a horizontal spring of spring constant of $400\:\mathrm{N m^{−1}}$. The other end of the spring is attached to a rigid wall. The mass is pushed so that at time $t = 0$ it is $4.0\:\mathrm{cm}$ closer to the wall than the equilibrium position and is travelling towards the wall with a velocity of $0.50\:\mathrm{m s^{−1}}$."

For the initial conditions, I wrote:

$$x(0)=0.04\:\mathrm{m}$$
$$v(0)=0.50\:\mathrm{m s^{−1}}$$

Yet I can't get the desirable answers. are my initial conditions correct? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your initial conditions are correct but you aren't actually doing anything with them.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? You're most likely wrong in your calculation method.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: $$x(t)=Acos(wt+\phi)$$
$$v(t)=-Awsin(wt+\phi)$$
then i plagged into initial condition values which gives me;
$$x(0)=Acos \phi$$
$$v(0)=-Awsin \phi$$
then i divided these two term, to determine $\phi$ yet i could not. should it be rad or in degrees?

Comment: i found at the end of my calculations that $tan \phi = 0,54$ but it is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial conditions are nearly correct, but not quite. The block starts off 0.04 metres to the *left* of the equilibrium position, meaning x(0)=-0.04m. Also, it is moving at 0.5m/s *to the left*, making its initial velocity v(0) equal -0.5m/s. Also, the x(t) and v(t) equations require ϕ be in radians. Try the equations again, and it will work. I hope this helped answer your question.